# Weird piece of paper I found on the ground

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I found this piece of paper on my way to a blimp, and was confused - please help!

Here is what it said:

> This is for someone jones-ing for a plant-based page-mystery featuring late-bonham activities.
>
> Here are the ones I think are rocking, in no order, perhaps with little quarters:
>
> StH
>
> WLL
>
> IS
>
> GtC
>
> WtLB
>
> GTBT
>
> BD
>
> tBoE

Don't be a rainy fool and help me make some sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each set of initials leads to:

> The title of a song by the rock band, Led Zeppelin

As follows:

> StH = *Stairway to Heaven*
>  WLL = *Whole Lotta Love*
>  IS = *Immigrant Song*
>  GtC = *Going to California*
>  WtLB = *When the Levee Breaks*
>  GTBT = *Good Times Bad Times*
>  BD = *Black Dog*
>  tBoE = *the Battle of Evermore*

The clues to this outcome are that:

> 1. The names of the members of the band are hidden in the text: *This is for someone **jones**-ing for a **plant**-based **page**-mystery featuring late-**bonham** activities.*
>  2. The mention of 'rocking'.
>  3. 'Little quarters' refers to *No Quarter*, another Led Zeppelin song.
>  4. The 'rainy fool' may be a reference to *The Rain Song*, also by Led Zeppelin.

Plus, of course:

> The 'blimp' i.e. zeppelin!

Comment: Yep all correct, including the hints and clues. Was my first riddle so I wasn't sure how many to have in there :)

Comment: @Cameron Well, welcome! You could probably get away with fewer clues in the text (maybe just one or two) and let the initials do the talking. When I spotted the surnames I knew immediately what you required of me! An air of mystery can be created just as much by what you *don't* put in as by what you do... Not a criticism, note - just a friendly tip :) Good luck with your next creation!